# I change my package name and then my application crash on main activity

Tags: android-studio

I changed my package name and after this my application crashed and showed me this error

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack available"

I've tried to rename the package but still I get the same issue.

Here is log from Logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.a786.paktourism/com.android.a786.paktourism.com.example.dreamwork_studios.paktourism.Splash}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.a786.paktourism.com.example.dreamwork_studios.paktourism.Splash"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.a786.paktourism-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2373)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.a786.paktourism.com.example.dreamwork_studios.paktourism.Splash"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.a786.paktourism-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
>         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.a786.paktourism.com.example.dreamwork_studios.paktourism.Splash
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                 ... 13 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

My app is running accurately and give me the results according to my expectations but now it crashes I don't know why...

Comment: Post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

if you change your package name manually, you should change the path of your manifest as well in `AndroidManifest.xml`

I also recommend you to run `clean/rebuild` after the package name changed in order to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: I changed my package name bu did'nt changed it in menifest but now it is working properly thanks for your precious time:)